# Angular - Access values of object stored in array of objects inside template

Tags: angular, typescript, angular5

I've got a single class as below:

```
export class SettingsTab {
  id: number;
  class: string;
  name: Object = {};
}
```

Also I mock it into simple array:

```
export const SETTINGSTABS: SettingsTab[] = [
  { id: 1, class: 'classOne', name: [{ "pl": "Tekst po polsku" }, { "en": "Text in english" }] },
  { id: 2, class: 'classTwo', name: [{ "pl": "Tekst po polsku" }, { "en": "Text in english" }] },
  { id: 3, class: 'classThree', name: [{ "pl": "Tekst po polsku" }, { "en": "Text in english" }] }
];
```

Now I would like to access certain value of name object in my template depending on which language I currently use. I get info about current language from localStorage as shown below:

```
language = localStorage.getItem('currentLang') != null ? localStorage.getItem('currentLang').replace("'", "") : "pl";
```

I managed to achieve it by code listed below:

```
<ng-container *ngFor="let name of settingsTab.name">
  <ng-container *ngFor="let key of ObjectKeys(name)">
    <span *ngIf="key == language">{{ name[key] }}</span>
  </ng-container>
</ng-container>
```

ObjectKeys are defined in my component as:

```
ObjectKeys = Object.keys;
```

But my question is there any easiest way to achieve what I want to do? Don't like two ng-components with *ngFor inside them. Also would like to achieve it in the most optimized way.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ideally, the property `name`:

```
{ ..., name: [{ "pl": "Tekst po polsku" }, { "en": "Text in english" }] },
```

Would have the format of not an array of objects, but an object:

```
{ ..., name: {"pl": "Tekst po polsku", "en": "Text in english"} },
```

Then you could simply use in your template:

```html
<span>{{ settingsTab.name[language] }}</span>
```

Which is a constant-time lookup (just getting a property in an object).

Now, if you can't change the format of `name`, I'd use a method instead of those nested `ng-container`s:

```
export class MyComponent {
  ...
  lang(names: [any], language: string) {
    return (names.find(lang => lang[language]) || {})[language]
  }
  ...
}
```

And use it like:

```html
<span>{{ lang(settingsTab.name, language) }}</span>
```

Of course, you can call `lang` whatever you see fit.
Just notice this alternative has O(n) complexity, due to `find` having to iterate the `name` array. This probably won't impact the performance of you application at all, but I thought you should know. In the current format of the `name`, there is no quicker way here.

Demo: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-c5wzbk?file=src/app/app.component.ts

Comment: Thaks! I can change the format of name property, so I went that way and it's working like a charm :)